# Change Product type in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I have two products and their type is "Grouped Product" now I want to change this products in to simple product. Is there any way to do so?

Some links says I have to change directly from database. I tried this but nothing changes. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only 2 maybe you should just create 2 new products with same url and change the url of the old ones.

Alternatively you could do some programming.

Maybe start with this class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped`.
the public function getAssociatedProducts returns an array of associated products which you can simply sort through applying whatever logic before creating your new products.

You have to deal with store scope etc during this process but there's lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

product type cannot be changed in admin!

may be you could go "catalog_product_entity" table and change the type_id from grouped to simple, but i dunno whether it induced new error, but one thing i only know is you must lost the grouped item linkage.

Comment: Only error is, the product options specific to the original type (ie. links to other products) do not get removed, but can no longer be reached. Not a bad thing, per se, it just wastes space in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Have you rebuilt the indices (Admin / System / Index Management) and refreshed the cache (Admin / System / Cache Management)?